# Random Visitor Sees Image

Tags: javascript, image, if-statement, random, var

I am trying to let my visitors have a 5% chance of seeing an image.

```
<script>
    var rand = Math.round(Math.rand() * 20)
    if (rand === 13) {
        document.write("<img src="http://ima.gs/69/666/314/Placeholder-401x401.png" />")
    }
</script>
```

Nothing happens when I run the script.

Comment: Probably *something* happens, if nowhere else then in the [error console](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bring up your developer tools, `cmd+shift i` or `ctrl+shift i` in Google Chrome.

The random method is not called `rand` it's called `random`.

```
var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * 20);
```

This is the error you would have seen in the javascript console `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'rand'`

Developer tools, what they are and how to use them:

- [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Tools)
- [Google Chrome](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/)

EDIT: 
As others have pointed out you also have a problem with your document.write argument. Any `"` that appears within a string enclosed with `"` must be escaped to not break the output as follow `\"` alternatively one can use `'` instead.

**Correctly escaped strings**

```
"<img src=\"http://ima.gs/69/666/314/Placeholder-401x401.png\" />"
"<img src='http://ima.gs/69/666/314/Placeholder-401x401.png' />"
'<img src="http://ima.gs/69/666/314/Placeholder-401x401.png" />'
'<img src=\'http://ima.gs/69/666/314/Placeholder-401x401.png\' />'
```

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Oops :P

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have too many double quotes. Try this instead:

```
document.write("<img src='http://ima.gs/69/666/314/Placeholder-401x401.png'/>")
```

Answer (score 3):

Besides using `Math.rand()` instead of `Math.random()` and some quoting issues, as others have mentioned, your code could be a bit shorter and more efficient.

```
<script>
   if(Math.random() < 0.05) {
      document.write("<img src='http://ima.gs/69/666/314/Placeholder-401x401.png' />");
   }
</script>
```

Also, I find `0.05` to reflect `5%` more clearly than "13 is 1 out of 20, which is 5%" ;-)

Comment: You missed that `Math.rand()` isn't a function.

Answer (score 3):

To generate a random number, use `Math.random()`, not `Math.rand()`

Comment: They also have a quoting problem.